# Splitting strings - isolating utterances in parliamentary debates

Tags: r, string, text, split

I have a data frame consisting of 500 written protocols of parliamentary debates, where every session represents a new row. My goal is to create a data frame in which each row is a unique utterance and where no parts of the strings are dropped.

The protocols have a standard format, in which each new utterance is introduced by the name and party/organisation of the speaker, followed by a colon. For example, these instances take the form of

"MP Peter Mueller (SPD):" or " "External Expert Petra Meier (German Trade Union):"

The protocols may look a little like this:

```
protocol <- "MP Peter Mueller (SPD): What do you think about the bill? External Expert Petra Meier (German Trade Union): I support the bill. MP Peter Mueller (SPD): Thank you for your expertise."
```

I am familiar with all the regular expressions I need to match and locate these instances of a new utterance. For this example, I would use.

```
utterances <- c(grep("MP \\w+ \\w+ \\(\\w+\\):", protocol),
                grep("External Expert \\w+ \\w+ \\(\\w+ \\w+ \\w+\\):", protocol))
```

I am now struggling to extract every new utterance as a substring and write it into a new row in my data frame. My expected output is:

```
dataframe
[1] "MP Peter Mueller (SPD): What do you think about the bill?" 
[2] "External Expert Petra Meier (German Trade Union): I support the bill." 
[3] "MP Peter Mueller (SPD): Thank you for your expertise."
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Using `protocol`, you can do `trimws(unlist(stri_split_regex(str = protocol, pattern = "(?<=[.|?])", omit_empty = T)))`. You need the stringi package. This line generates the expected character vector.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. I'll leave it as an answer below later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave what I said in my comment here. Using the provided example (i.e., protocol), one suggestion is the following. You want to split strings with a space which follows either `?` or `.`. Here I used `stri_split_regex()` in the stringi package. But you can use any other similar functions.

```
trimws(unlist(stri_split_regex(str = protocol, pattern = "(?<=[.|?])", omit_empty = T)))

#[1] "MP Peter Mueller (SPD): What do you think about the bill?"            
#[2] "External Expert Petra Meier (German Trade Union): I support the bill."
#[3] "MP Peter Mueller (SPD): Thank you for your expertise."
```